# How to run javascript in gvim?

Tags: javascript, vim

My system : xp + gvim.
I have open gvim to edit a  javascript sentence ,the file has no name yet.

```
print(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

I want to map `<F7>` to javascript ,how can i write the map sentence in `_vimrc`?
How  can i get `55`  when i input `F7`  when the configuration finished?

I do as `elclanrs` say ,error output is

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ( node ^<C:\DOCUME~1\sanya\LOCALS~1\Temp\VIi8C.tmp)    
[stdin]:1    
print(sum(range(1, 10)));    
      ^    
ReferenceError: range is not defined    
    at [stdin]:1:11    
    at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)    
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)    
    at evalScript (node.js:532:25)    
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (node.js:154:11)    
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)    
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16    
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)    
shell returned 8    
Hit any key to close this window...
```

[image]

Comment: Learn to use markdown, it will seriously help you getting help. @elclanrs answer is correct, if you have troubles with node, ask new questions on stack overflow with the node.js tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to run JavaScript in VIM is to install [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) then you can run your current buffer in Node with VIM using

```
:w !node
```

You don't even need to save it. Use `console.log`:

```
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

Mapping F7. Works on current file:

```
map <F7> :call Run() <cr>
function Run()
  exec "! node %"
endfunction
```

To execute it in the browser you'd simply write it as a script in HTML:

```
<script>
  alert('in browser!');
</script>
```

And run it the browser, with F5 for example:

```
map <F5> <Esc>:silent !google-chrome %<cr>
```

Comment: Variant:  define `Run()` to do `execute '!node console.log(' getline('.') ')'` (untested).  That should execute the current line.